# Can not use WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization

Tags: c#, .net, graph, charts, uwp

I have a Universal Windows Application with a single window. On that window i want to display a chart with the extension

> WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization

I can not install the extension, because it `does not target .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2`. I tried the most recent version, v2.3.0.

Changing the .NETFramework to older/newer won't solve the problem but will also have effect on other extensions.

Will i need another extension or is there a way to get this running?

**Edit**

> Error: Could not install package 'WinRTXamlToolkit 2.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

This is the nuget package manager use. It is german, but should be easy to understand.

[image]

Comment: how do you install it? using nuget package manager? I have no trouble installing this exact version of extension to a newly created project (v4.5.2).

Comment: Yes i am using nuget package manager

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the error (showing the searched packages)? I guess you are installing a wrong extension.

Comment: I posted the error right under the question. The screenshot does not provide any additional information.

Comment: yes, i saw that. That is in the output window, i mean the [NuGet window](http://sibeeshpassion.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Manage-NuGet-Package-Window-1024x407.png), where you use the search and select package.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, looks like your project is a WPF project, not UWP.

(I dedduce this from MainWindow.xaml as seen in the screen capture. You define pages in a UWP project, and navigate them within a chrome, so in UWP, you get MainPage from the project template. MainWindow, on the other hand, is a WPF convention.)

Try using "WPFToolkit.DataVisualization" instead.